# is there a way to load a gz file in java?

Tags: java

I chart history files stored as gz files.
Is there a way I can load a gz file in java
so far the nly results i got from google is to run external program to decompress it ,  I rather have it done within java.

Comment: Did you try searching for “java gzip”?

Comment: What do you mean by **load a gz file in java**? Is this of no help to you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080381/gzipinputstream-reading-line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

You can try GZIPInputStream class.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html

There are two main methods in this class for closing stream and reading data.

**void close()**
Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

**int   read(byte[] buf, int off, int len)**
Reads uncompressed data into an array of bytes.

This guy asked similar question on [Extract .gz files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999813/extract-gz-files-in-java) so you can try to use it as sample.

This is the sample:

```
public static void gunzipIt(String name){

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try{

    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("/var/www/html/grepobot/API/"+ name + ".txt.gz"));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/var/www/html/grepobot/API/"+ name + ".txt");

    int len;
    while ((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    gzis.close();
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Extracted " + name);

} catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add a short summary of the link you provided. Links are welcome on SO but they tend to rot.

Comment: Added. Thank you for suggestion.